# Schedule sh script on Android

Tags: android, shell, automation, schedule

Can I schedule a sh script to run on a certain time on my Android phone?

Like crontab does on Linux. My Android phone is not rooted and preferably I'd keep it that way. But rooting is an option.

The script sends certain taps:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
input tap 400 400
sleep 1
...
```

When connected through adb (`adb shell`) I can run the script with `sh /storage/emulated/0/myscript.sh`. Which works perfectly.

Preferable I'd have an easy way to set and unset the time of the scheduled job. The script taps on a LED strip color picking app and my goal is to simulate a sunrise of about 15 mins which I can schedule the night before to wake me up.

Comment: Might be better to reverse engineer the app's apk, and add code to it

Comment: Unfortunately I can't program Java or Android apps

Comment: Probably not going to be easily possible due to the vulnerabilities it'd open up, but you can have a read of this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/140162/creating-a-cron-job-on-android